# Django-Orm Нужно составить запрос, который найдёт последнюю книгу каждого автора

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```
# Код на django

class Autors(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    author = models.ForegnKey("Autors", models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Предположим, есть две такие модели. У каждого автора много книг, и нужно получить список книг, в котором будет находится одна, последняя книга каждого автора в бд.

Comment: Какая книга считается "последней"? Книга с наибольшим id?

Comment: @andreymal, по времени лучше.

Comment: Если datetime является датой добавления книги, рекомендую переименовать в что-нибудь более конкретное вроде created_at

Comment: @andreymal, согласен. Просто пример.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен список, то будет что-то вроде этого:

```
books = []
for author in Authors.objects.all():
    books.append(Book.objects.filter(author__name=author.name).order_by('-created_at').first())
```

Comment: Не подойдёт. Нужно же, чтобы одним запросом, а здесь их много сгенерируется.